# Combinar un fichero y un generador de números aleatorios

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que, basado en un número aleatorio, seleccione la línea correspondiente a ese número y la imprima en pantalla, pero necesito que me imprima, la asociada al número aleatorio, y las 4 siguientes, ya que se trata de una pregunta y sus cuatro opciones. Este proceso se ha de repetir "x" veces (en este caso 20 veces) y necesito que cada vez imprima una pregunta distinta, pero no pasa nada si esporádicamente alguna pregunta se repite.

Tan sólo tengo esto, alguien me podría ayudar? Muchas gracias de antemano. (El while lo he puesto porque necesito que la primera línea que imprima sea múltiplo de 5)

```
void preguntasyrespuestastrivial() {
  system("cls");

  int i;
  i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    cout << "Pregunta " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;

    ifstream archivo_entrada("preguntas.txt");;
    string linea;
    int contador = 0;
    int aleatorio;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int DESDE = 0, HASTA = 56;

    aleatorio = rand() % (HASTA - DESDE + 1) + DESDE;

    while ((aleatorio != 5) && ((aleatorio != 10) && (aleatorio != 15) && (aleatorio != 20) && (aleatorio != 25) && (aleatorio != 30) && ((aleatorio != 35) && (aleatorio != 40) && (aleatorio != 45) && (aleatorio != 50)))) {
      aleatorio = rand() % (HASTA - DESDE + 1) + DESDE;
    }
    cin >> aleatorio;

    while (getline(archivo_entrada, linea)) {

      if (aleatorio == contador) {
        cout << linea << endl;
      }
      contador++;
    }
    
    system("pause");
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes usar el operador `%` para simplificar el ciclo while. Algo como `while(aleatorio % 5 != 0 and aleatorio <= 5 and aleatorio >= 50)`

Comment: Fantástico, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

El uso de las funciones `rand` y `srand` está desaconsejado en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), primero porque son utilidades de cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y segundo porque son unas funciones inseguras, son propensas a fallos y son ineficientes (hasta el punto de que se ha [propuesto deprecarlas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf)).

Dado que programas en C++, debes usar las utilidades de generación de números pseudo-aleatorios de dicho lenguaje, la cabecera `<random>`. Asi pues, si necesitas un número aleatorio entre *A* y *B*, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Habiendo incluido <random>:

std::random_device dispositivo;                     // Se usa para obtener la raíz aleatoria
std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());              // Usa el algoritmo mersenne_twister_engine
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(A, B); // Los números generados estarán entre A y B


auto numero = distribucion(generador); // Generamos un número pseudo-aleatorio
```

Si necesitas que los números se generen como múltiplos de cinco, no generes números al tuntún y descartes los que no te valgan, eso es terriblemente ineficiente pues tu generación falla el 80% de las veces. Simplemente genera un número y multiplícalo por cinco.

También es terriblemente ineficiente abrir el archivo de preguntas cada vez que quieres acceder a un quinteto de ellas, lo mejor es leer en memoria todas las preguntas y trabajar los datos desde ahí. Con estos cambios, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int main()
{
    const auto preguntas = leer_preguntas();

    std::random_device dispositivo;
    std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(0, 4);

    for (int pregunta = distribucion(generador) * 5, fin = pregunta + 5; pregunta != fin; ++pregunta)
        std::cout << preguntas[pregunta] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXPT2RFED4zf0W5HnZG0CwqURYWg2RiTJZ1XUOMUUN6umseTfp1PfrHBDB78E/Z4x44GG5cTHx/GFb1ezPDwGLigTCvu7rqq6@/@lo3zaeV1re3H1uvXTYIu5ZiCqjqvcFyLShvaGVlhjpRuLvCp6yv9gaDmMzz593@bvnd74BDDMdNwCr7pOJwtDMYWJ@gVtYPR4M/BmuafEygciJYhMGLD51bK4k7WMcGZ1YjGBsbijbZGe30AXXa3N7@4iuo0GNQhsLwTtBwNJrHZW@nFOpjhnPMEYx3kpMlv7sH80/Nn8NnG/BlKc/RMBTwc1gMcyVyUXEEn8DWBkyt55BF9Dps7Sy/Pnoh@zuwvj5fGg3WOmSacoLd3SUfv85//S7LT3/zTwVPwJSDh2c7g7f/4wKE8@7kYI1/rj355@8fc/seTlCfEJzYSwKMSTmnAjgFr4OtuSn4LmPgf4fZG6vcN082uqMHuX3nQAI4tiaPRgGz6Oyl4l/oYRwb1f6lQPmEEQxycA60OF9KG4qA542jQh6HTbkYeXCy7rUKlZIQFpzpQDU9qFlGx1QqBzXjWmYdeziTxDY61WXQyP1wSgWvVEMO22sPKbDSGgwGS9KJKl1LmZ9VwuDoLkzbvvcQEUSu1khxbqViMcot6Rwii6N0d86K4JJMko31MsN@hyjgxZ0UXKqksHVDISk5JWlrmtnaoueRYIhJTVWwS8apb85TPQnYYyLdXqnH72tBv4RE0YJRq3eAddNpFwLVyhOw0BlBew0kG4HLNIoTniiN8pE9aFVPLEnSiOfLTg/a65oEFpNZ83luqLsvYUoa58Q9EoM16aBK20UnVBZjw4g6sUyZnrO8wqRIjqmJIPERUp4VDCZLIrlXt@heqnDIAXMJ@xL9EGThjnujJrNC6gKOE@hgo2X18TZHWl1ybW5/vn1f@VH666@ia2quo1qF9irZujv69bOt1Q5MVz6wFOXUD6@O7ncoLXWbP3U3Bm@waW8mTuCM53w9EL222SgDMztjNuCQtU/wmtzD6ZDzgsF6gw2yTi45fhwdzdDbgvqXXBGP0MyqD7bd5IJSMkwdC1/IZ8Jk6yzj6rTIgtJqUkQ6FoD7PtkqK7joMFhRwXzvEI29J1BWYSSvTnEuUOaj513mv1P3aXb2kUY59Unmg1byNzZ2zL7Mnu2EwtJS8JJNYkLBUH@fXs0Q9tk0CDY3@9xHns3btdeRpsQjbLGiZa@T4khKetPEKsvCCNZlnmWqKpkz8cZEhh3I8Z@mqOJncG94OFNf75AuZdiERPZGDnfkxWKpYOcCLIarWKy1QSqJyj1x8D0PK@7KWir@quZi4U7fMKtiDe1N2XB4gUuTeMmRXMEUVRzIi82GYj01Yie24pfU6m7U5c2Twf1e/ITd4VuGWUIF1KrysuZbbq@XJeQ57meYy2ieYd/Z/qS9mSonDxPIfaX2nU79TFYy6daVkUV5c3pCTnGKUPNDlJQYM7R/TgMf@Q@OFy4vDD9mWmPuXN6iI9ZRbydv@f29vf0X)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tanta info, usaré todo lo que pueda, la verdad que me has ayudado un montón, gracias!!!!